# how to remove ubuntu without keyboard, mouse, and cd drive

Tags: grub2, windows, uninstall

is there anyway i can remove ubuntu without a keyboard nor mouse(I can use my mouse and keyboard in windows), and no cd drive. I could delete the ubuntu partition in windows but if i do so how can i delete it while keeping the grub loader for booting?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your windows you should be able to access the "windows recovery enviroment" by pressing F8 while booting into windows.
There you schould be able to fix the MBR (somewhere in systemrepair).
When your MBR is back to normal (you don't see grup anymore) you can safely remove the ubuntu partition.

If you delete the ubuntu-partiotion before you end up in grub's rescue mode.
**I recomment to not let that happen**, but from there you should still be able to boot into windows.